# Não consigo receber os valores de um formulário PHP via POST

Tags: php, aplicação-web, formulário, post

Estou tendo um problema em um formulário php que não sei como resolver.
Eu tenho um arquivo chamado login.php que é contem um formulário que envia os dados via POST para o arquivo dados.php. No dados.php eu faço o processamento necessário. Acontece que sempre que tento simular um login, recebo a seguinte mensagem: 
Notice: Undefined variable: usuario
Notice: Undefined variable: pass
Meu código do login.php é esse:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<form  method="POST" action="dados.php">
    <label>Login</label>
    <input type="text" name="usuario" class="form-control" id="usuario" autocomplete="off" autofocus required>

    <label for="senha">Senha</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pass" name="pass" autocomplete="off" required>

    <input type="submit" value="Login" id="entrar" name="entrar">
</form>

    <!-- Scripts -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/ocultarSenha.js"></script>
```

Meu código do dados.php é esse:

```
<?php
    // Conexão com o banco
    $bdServidor = '127.0.0.1';
    $bdUsuario = 't3carvvo_MatheusEdnei';
    $bdSenha = 't3carvvo_#';
    //$bdUsuario = 'root';
    //$bdSenha = 'root';
    $bdBanco = 't3carvvo_pessoas';

    $conexao = mysqli_connect($bdServidor, $bdUsuario, $bdSenha, $bdBanco);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno($conexao)) {
        echo "Problemas para conectar no banco. Erro:";
        echo mysqli_connect_errno;
        die();
    }

    if (isset($_POST['usuario'])) {
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
        echo "entrei no usuario  ";
        echo $usuario;
    } else {
        echo "não entrei no usuario";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {
        $pass = MD5($_POST['pass']);
        echo "entrei na senha   ";
        echo $pass; 
    } else {
        echo "não entrei na senha";
    }


    $contem = strpos($usuario, '@');
    if($contem === false){
        echo "cpf";

    } else {
        $sqlSelecionarEmail = "SELECT email FROM pessoa WHERE email = '$usuario'";
        $selecaoEmail = mysqli_query($sqlSelecionarEmail,$conexao);
        $arrayEmail = mysqli_fetch_array($selecaoEmail);
        print($arrayEmail);
        $loginarray = $arrayEmail['email'];

        $sqlSelecionarSenha = "SELECT senha FROM pessoa WHERE senha = '$pass'";
        $selecaoSenha = mysqli_query($sqlSelecionarSenha,$conexao);
        $arraySenha = mysqli_fetch_array($selecaoSenha);
        $senhaArray = $arraySenha['senha'];

        if($loginarray === $usuario and $senhaArray === $pass ) {
            echo"
            <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Login e senha corretos');
                //window.location.href='dados.php';
            </script>
            ";
        } else {
            echo"
            <script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
                alert('Login ou senha incorretos');
                window.location.href='dados.php';
            </script>
            ";
        }

    }

?>
```

Edit 1:

Modifiquei um pouco o código e agora o retorno é o seguinte:

Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\t3carvvo_tarefa1\dados.php on line 31

Notice: Undefined index: pass in C:\xampp\htdocs\t3carvvo_tarefa1\dados.php on line 32

Notice: Undefined index: usuario in C:\xampp\htdocs\t3carvvo_tarefa1\dados.php on line 33

Comment: ele não exibe a linha onde está dando o erro?

Comment: Ele imprime a mensagem de "não entrei no usuário" que indica que o isset($_POST['usuario']) retorna um valor vazio. Se eu retirar essa verificação ele me informa que a um erro de indice quando faço : $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];

Comment: ja tentou dar um `var_dump($_POST)` , para ver se esta recendo algo?

Comment: Eu fiz isso agora e ele me retornou: array(0) { } . Observando as ferramentas do desenvolvedor do Chrome na aba de network percebi que o "Request method" esta indicando que a requisição foi do tipo GET, mesmo colocando o form como POST.

Answer (score 0):

Eu executei o seu código e encontrei os seguintes erros:

Nas linhas onde você usa a função `mysqli_query` os parâmetros da função estão trocados, o primeiro parâmetro deve ser `$conexão` e o segundo `$sqlSelecionarEmail`.

Errado:

```php
$selecaoEmail = mysqli_query($sqlSelecionarEmail,$conexao);
```

Certo:

```php
$selecaoEmail = mysqli_query($conexao, $sqlSelecionarEmail);
```

Outro erro é na linha onde você faz `print($arrayEmail);`. Aqui o erro é que você esta passando um array mas a função `printf` espera uma string como parâmetro.